# How to set date 1/1/1753 in java

Tags: java, calendar

I am using following code to set currebnt date-

```
session.getCurrentDate().getTime()
```

Now i want to set the minimum date ie- 1/1/1753, is there any constant or function for doing this other than explicitly hardcoding it.

Comment: I need to set date 1/1/1753, it is the default date i guess.

Comment: Well it's probably safe to say this is too localized.

Answer (score 6):

do this

```
Calendar c1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
  c1.set(1753, Calendar.JANUARY, 01);  //January 1st 1753
```

Comment: I am curious to know why your comment has January 30th 2000?

Comment: Yes, what was the January 30th 2000?

Comment: guys i am really impressed with your curiosity but check the answer now..

Comment: Why GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); Calender.getInstance provides an object of GregorianCalendar. So why do we need to tell it explicitly..

Comment: You need to be aware that the hrs, mins + seconds will have some random value unless you set them

Comment: @Murali - Thanks...so that means there is no calender function that sets the date to 1/1/1753  without hardcoding it, I was expecting that there would be some standard constant representing this date.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a default date to be set.

I would create a String and then simply parse it to get the required date.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date myDefaultDate = format.parse("1/1/1753");
```

Now `myDefaultDate` will contain the date "1/1/1753".

Comment: We must avoid using Date API in our new code, as Date API is deprecated, so no additional work is done on it, and top of it java can get ride of it soon

Comment: so you can use the Calendar example given in @Murali 's answer

Comment: No call in this is actually deprecated (as of 1.7).  But you should use the Calendar class for date conversions.

Answer (score 1):

The default is the current time - see the parameterless constructor.

The switch to the Gregorian calendar happened on different dates. The GregorianCalendar class uses October 4, 1582, the date the first group of countries changed over, as the default change date.

You can obtain the default change date using `new GregorianCalendar().getGregorianChange()`.

That is not the earliest possible date because GregorianCalendar uses the Julian calendar before the change over. In any case, the calendar is projected both into the past, even before creation of the Julian calendar, and into the future.